# Return View not returning - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Well, this sound simple, and I've done it a dozen times already in my project, but this time isn't working and I don't know why. I just want to call a view, that have the name of the controller method. So, I have an Ajax POST in one of my Views, that is the following:

```
$(".btn-default").on("click", function (event, params) {
console.log($(".chosen-select").val());

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EditPfEsp", "Lottery")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    traditional : true,
    data: { bdoIds: $(".chosen-select").val() },
    success: function (response) {
    if (response.length > 0) {
    alert(response);
    }
    else {
    alert("response length zero");
    }
    }
    });
```

It calls the method EditPfEsp just fine, which is this:

```
public ActionResult EditPfEsp(string[] bdoIds)
    {
        IEnumerable<PF> pF = new List<PF>();
        pF = service.GetPF();
        List<PF> pFList = new List<PF>();
        pFList = pF.ToList();
        List<PF> pfListFinal = new List<PF>();

        for (int i = 0; i < bdoIds.Count(); i++ )
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < pFList.Count(); x++)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(bdoIds[i]);
                int pfunc = Convert.ToInt32(pFList[x].Func);
                if (id == pfunc && (pFList[x].Tipo_sorteio == "ESPECIAL" || pFList[x].Tipo_sorteio == "especial" || pFList[x].Tipo_sorteio == "Especial"))
                {
                    pfListFinal.Add(pFList[x]);
                }
            }
        }

        IEnumerable<PF> pfIE = new List<PF>();
        pfIE = pfListFinal.AsEnumerable();

        return View(pfIE);
    }
```

But then, the method doesn't return the view EditPfEsp that I have (same directory and same controller as the others. What I am doing wrong? I can't get this working and I don't have idea why.

**edit**

This is the EditPfEsp view that I want to show from my controller

```
    @model IEnumerable<AldpModel.Entities.PF>



<h2>Editar ponderações de funcionários selecionados</h2>

<div class="filterbox">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tipo_sorteio)</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Funcionario)</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome_Funcionario)</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ponderacao)</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Incluir_sorteio)</b>
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tipo_sorteio)
                </td>
                <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Funcionario)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Funcionario)
                </td>
                <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ponderacao)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Incluir_sorteio)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.Funcionario }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Apagar", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If your returning html, then it needs to be `dataType: 'html',` (not json), and the response is html so `if (response.length > 0) {` probably does not make much sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke But Stephen, the ajax is before calling the method. And it call the method without problems, and pass the parameters fine. The problem is in the method, that not return any View

Comment: `return View(pfIE);` returns html, but you specify that the ajax result accept only `json`

Comment: You could check the details of the requests - especially the response - in your Browsers' Developer-Console to see whats going on. Other than that Muecke is right, you have to either change your ajax call to accept `text/html` or change the return type of `EditPfEsp` to `JsonResult`, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Changed the ajax datatype to html. Continues the same, I'm not being returned to any view after calling the EditPfEsp controller. Will try see the developer console

Comment: Which view is it returning?

Comment: @AmanBaloch The view with the same name of the method. The view is called EditPfEsp

Comment: add a ajax request check from request header and based on the check if a ajax function is calling this Action then use, return PartialView(pfIE) instead;

Comment: What this $(".chosen-select").val() is producing?

Comment: @Mariusz The values selected from a list. The bdoIds passed to the EditPfEsp controller are for example:  {string[2]}, and the values [0] = 249 and [1] = 64

Comment: @danielpm Is the ajax Success method being called? If not have tried checking the error function?

Comment: @AmanBaloch I think so, at least the values are passed right to the controller. How can I see that? Tried with developer tools but cant see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create the `<div id='id'></div>` ,then hit your specific actionresult for edit so actionresult return to you partialview(model) and then append your partailveiw with `$("id").empty().append(response)`.

Comment: This works more or less like I wanted! This makes that the view appear in the current view. But I wanted to open a new window with the view that I want to show! Can I do that?

Comment: This worked for me, inserting the view that I wanted in my atual view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your ajax function to include the error callback function as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("EditPfEsp", "Lottery")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    traditional : true,
    data: { bdoIds: $(".chosen-select").val() },
    success: function (response) {
      if (response.length > 0) {
      alert(response);
      }
      else {
      alert("response length zero");
      }
    }
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
       alert(textStatus);
       alert(errorThrown);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Yes it does! "Error" and "Internal Server Error". Why's that? From where they come from? It gives me the error after pass my entire controller!

Comment: Exception may be thrown  because for example you are passing to View wrong model.

Comment: @Mariusz I'm passing the correct model to the view!

Comment: When I debug the application, my controller receives the values fine. I will update the topic with the view from where i want to go

Comment: @AmanBaloch In visualstudio, If i put a break in the script it wont hit. But using firebug I can see that is something with the ajax callback. I add the "complete: function( jqXHR, status) {alert("alert")} and it fires in the callback, but then nothing happend like before

Comment: @danielpm you can put a break point in the view which is being returned. I suspect you have an error there, possibly a null exception

Comment: @AmanBaloch Putting a break in my View (in the foreach), I can see that the model (and the variables) are being passed correctly. Thought, I dont get the errors from ajax, only the complete alert. But after that, I still not being returned to the View (even if in the debug he pass there)

Comment: You will have a view in your views folder called EditPfEsp, you should debug that not the controller method

Comment: @AmanBaloch And there is where I had put the break. Even if I try to change the return View to a RedirectToAction("Index","PF"), it dont work. Isn't anything with the Ajax? I already tried put [HttpGet] before my controller method, but it dont work also

Comment: @AmanBaloch updated the start thread with the full view! Do you have an Ideia of what i could be?

Comment: @danielpm they way you're creating your table headers will throw an exception. Because your model is an enumerable and you are accessing it as an entity <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tipo_sorteio)</b>
            </th>

Comment: @AmanBaloch I used the Rughaani solution below, calling the html page to my atual page throught the Ajax. For now, it's working more or less like i wanted. Thank you so much for your help and time!